# Quartz.NET filter INFO messages

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.NET in one of my applications, configured to do the logging using log4net. So far so good, everything works as expected.

However, there's one thing that bothers me. When I'm using INFO as logging level, is there any way to filter out Quartz.NET messages from the log?

A typical log file looks like this:

```
2016-05-13 16:30:32,608 - Application start
2016-05-13 16:30:32,646 - [Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory] - INFO - Using default implementation for object serializer
2016-05-13 16:30:32,677 - [Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory] - INFO - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
2016-05-13 16:30:32,677 - [Quartz.Core.SchedulerSignalerImpl] - INFO - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: Quartz.Core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2016-05-13 16:30:32,677 - [Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler] - INFO - Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.3.0 created.
2016-05-13 16:30:32,677 - [Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin] - INFO - Registering Quartz Job Initialization Plug-in.
2016-05-13 16:30:32,677 - [Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore] - INFO - RAMJobStore initialized.
2016-05-13 16:30:32,692 - [Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler] - INFO - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.3.0) 'ArchiveAppScheduler' with instanceId 'ArchiveApp'
  Scheduler class: 'Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

2016-05-13 16:30:32,692 - [Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory] - INFO - Quartz scheduler 'ArchiveAppScheduler' initialized
2016-05-13 16:30:32,692 - [Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory] - INFO - Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.3.0
2016-05-13 16:30:32,692 - [Quartz.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor] - INFO - Parsing XML file: quartz_jobs.xml with systemId: quartz_jobs.xml
2016-05-13 16:30:32,846 - [Quartz.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor] - INFO - Adding 1 jobs, 1 triggers.
2016-05-13 16:30:32,846 - [Quartz.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor] - INFO - Adding job: MainJob.ArchiveDB
2016-05-13 16:30:32,862 - [Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler] - INFO - Scheduler ArchiveAppScheduler_$_ArchiveApp started.
2016-05-13 16:30:32,878 - [ArchiveApp.ArchiveDB] - INFO - Archiving process started
2016-05-13 16:30:32,878 - [ArchiveApp.Helpers] - INFO - Reading SyncRepositoryServerName setting
```

Is there any way to filter out all [Quartz.#######] messages?

Comment: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html - "Suppose we are no longer interested in seeing the output of any component belonging to the Com.Foo package..."

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
 <logger name="Quartz">
    <level value="OFF" />
 </logger>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.